# php code to grab set of characters from .php file giving error message

Tags: php, string, variables, constants

Thanks in advance.

Getting this warning when using below code:

Warning: file_get_contents(test.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/index.php on line so-n-so.

Here's the code I am using,

```
<?php

// Scan directory for files
$dir = "path/";
$files = scandir($dir);

// Iterate through the list of files 
foreach($files as $file)
{
// Determine info about the file
$parts = pathinfo($file);

// If the file extension == php
if ( $parts['extension'] === "php" )
{
// Read the contents of the file
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// Find first occurrence of opening template tag
$from = strpos($contents, "{{{{{");

// Find first occurrence of ending template tag
$to = strpos($contents,"}}}}}");

// Pull out the unique name from between the template tags
$uniqueName = substr($contents, $from+5, $to);

// Print out the unique name
echo $uniqueName ."<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that the file isn't found.

This is because [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) returns only the basename of the files from your directory. It doesn't include the directory name. You could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) instead:

```
$files = glob("$dir/*.php");
```

This returns the path in the result list, and would also make your extension check redundant.

Comment: Yes, it is finding the files. But `file_get_contents` cannot read it without knowing the path to it. And your code currently only passes `"file.php"` not the required `"path/file.php"` to file_get_contents; hence the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you need to exclude `.` and `..` from the list of files picked up by [`scandir()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

```
// Iterate through the list of files 
foreach($files as $file) {
    if('.' == $file or '..' == $file) {
        continue;
    }
...
```

Also you need to put the path before your file name:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($path . $file);
```